# How to get link to respect padding around text

Tags: html, css

Currently the link is just around the text / `li`. How do I get the link to respect the padding on the `li`? i.e. for the full height of the list item to be clickable / the yellow background on hover to fill the height of the list item including the padding top and bottom.

For various reasons I don't want to add the padding top and bottom to the link `a` style. it has to be on the `li` element

```css
ul {
  font-size:22px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-top:1px solid;
  line-height:35px; 
}

li {
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  padding:18px 0;
}

a:link { color:rgb(66,66,66); display:block; }
a:visited { color:rgb(66,66,66); display:block; }
a:hover { color:rgb(66,66,66); display:block; background-color:yellow; }
a:active { color:rgb(66,66,66); display:block; background-color:yellow; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Coming soon</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ah7qyfc/

Comment: This is difficult to achieve without some JS, because even though you can change the style of the `li` to have the same background as the link on hover, clicking on the `li` will not follow the link unless you happen to be over the block with the `a` in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the area of the link element with a pseudoelement positioned in `absolute` according to the `list-item`.

Add `position: relative` to the `li`, then for the `::before` pseudoelement of the link set `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` (so even if you change the value of the padding of the parent element, the clickable area will adapt itself).

```css
ul {
    font-size:22px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    border-top:1px solid;
    line-height:35px; 
}

li {
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    padding:18px 0;
    position: relative;
}

a::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li:hover { background: yellow; }


a, 
a:link, 
a:visited, 
a:hover,
a:active { color:rgb(66,66,66); display:block; }
  
a:hover, 
a:active { background: inherit;  }
```

```html
<ul id="list-of-posts" class="cms-editable">
    <li><a href="index.html">Coming soon</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

As the final result, the top and bottom padding areas are clickable.

Comment: Presumably to get the color background on hover I'd have to add li:hover { background-color:yellow; }

Comment: yes, if that is the effect you want. But Instead of declaring twice the hover color, you may set `a:hover { background: inherit }` (see my edit)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I hadn't realised it was going to be so difficult

Answer (score -2):

Try with this CSS:

```
li:hover{
  color:rgb(66,66,66); display:block; background-color:yellow;
}
```

You can add id="" if necessary.

Comment: This will not make the padded area clickable, which is in the question: _i.e. for the full height of the list item to be clickable_